# Get latest/last items from the list which is in ascending order

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ query and I am getting list of items in ascending order. I need to get the latest 4 items from that list.

I have Load more button, onclick of which should get the previous 4 items from that list.

```
   var GetALLFields =(from post in dbContext.PostTable
                                              join com in dbContext.CommentTable on post.PostID equals com.PostedId
                                              join user in dbContext.UserTable on com.commenterID equals user.userId
                                              where (com.PostedId == PostID)

                                              select new
                                              {
                                                  PostId = post.PostID,
                                                  commentId = com.commentID,
                                                  CommenterID = user.userId,
                                                  name = user.Name,
                                                  commenterUserName = user.userName,
                                                  Imagebase64 = user.userImageBase64,
                                                  ImageType = user.userImagetype,
                                                  commentId = post.PostedDataID,
                                                                              commentcreatedAt = com.createdAt,
                                                  commenterDelete = com.commenterDelete,
                                              });  


   if (GetALLFields != null)
                    {
   //PageSize I am getting from ajax (first it be 0 then pageSize will be multple of 4)
                        GetALLComment = GetALLFields.OrderBy(x=>x.createdAt).Skip(PageSize).Take(4).Reverse().ToList();
                        GetALLComment.Reverse();
                    }
```

Onpage load, I need to get latest/last 4 items from the list

```
7
8
9
10
```

OnClick of Load more, I need to get previous 4 items along with latest 4 items

```
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
```

Comment: so you need the results to be adding up?

Comment: if that's the case, You may post the ajax where you are populating it. Thats where you need to edit! this code is doing it's job!

Comment: Your actual problem than

Comment: The first time, it has to take 7 8 9 10 and on 2nd time, it has to take 3 4 5 6 and merge it with first one.

Comment: What is the issue with your current code?

Comment: The issue is, the first time it gets 7 8 9 10 and on click of Load More, it's again getting me the same 7 8 9 10 and NOT 3 4 5 6 which I need.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Reverse() method two times.Remove Reverse() from one of step.
Like this :

```
GetALLComment=GetALLFields.OrderBy(x=>x.createdAt).Skip(PageSize).Take(4).ToList();
GetALLComment.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're reversing the records after you take them then reverse them again, those two commands cancel themselves out.

If you want the lastest records first just use OrderByDescending and if you also want to take 8 items at the second reload, you need to take PageSize*4 items

```
GetALLComment = GetALLFields.OrderByDescending(x=>x.createdAt).Skip(PageSize).Take(PageSize*4).ToList();
```

then reverse them so that they are ascending

```
GetALLComment.Reverse();
```